# Passing initParams tag value to mainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have `initParams` tag, which specify which child window to load in a navigation based Silverlight application. I set it in web project. Consume it in `App.xaml.cs` inside `Application_Startup` event.

But, i need to pass this to `MainPage.xaml.cs`, so that i could load the appropriate child window. How do it set it with **this.RootVisual**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of `InitParams` is also available statically as:-

```
 Application.Current.Host.InitParams
```

However why would you want to pass this to `MainPage` only to have it replace the `RootVisual`?  It would be better for the code in *App.xaml.cs* to determine which page should be the `RootVisual` and assign it once.

Comment: Instead of a simple silverlight application, i want to build a business application. So, that i could run it as standalone application. Also, i could embed individual xaml pages at specific site pages. I was able to get the InitParams using your suggest, but not able to load appropriate child window from navigation control. Which i shall search tomorrow. Thanks.